# change HTML option select as icon style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make select options look like icons?

I mean when you click on an icon the select menu will appear instead of the box style. Is that possible?

I mean something like this

https://image.ibb.co/gBY31U/testset.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function dropdowntoggle() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0];
    if (dropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      dropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
    var selections = document.getElementsByClassName('selection');
    for(var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
        var selection = selections[i];
        selection.onclick = function() {
            console.log(this.innerText);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.without-button {
    width: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="dropdowntoggle()" class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="selection" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a class="selection" href="#about">About</a>
    <a class="selection" href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- uncomment this to see same behaviour without button -->
<!-- <div onclick="dropdowntoggle()" class="dropbtn without-button">
   <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div> -->
```

Comment: No   I mean when I click  on icon select menu will open  so  the box style will be changed by icon  I hope it's clear now  if now I can show you and image

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/gBY31U/testset.png

Comment: 'box style will be changed by icon' - I don't understand this

Comment: What is box style?

Comment: in normal select style there are rectangle box  when you click on it it will show the options correct ?   in my case look at the image there's an icon instead  when you click on it  it will show select options, so how can I change the rectangle style to an icon   instead of clicking on rectangle box  like normal  I want to remove it and add icon  instead

Comment: Got it :) In that case a `select` tag wouldn't work. We need a normal `div` and some event listeners. Have a look at my updated answer. Hope it suffices.

Comment: Thank you very much Ray  thats more then what I asked for.  I appreciate your time and effort to help me I will study your code to know how did you do it.

Comment: You're welcome :) You can have a look at the original code that I used https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown
I modified it to include an icon instead of text

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a font-awesome icon to your select dropdown (as text!). You only need a few things in CSS only, the FontAwesome CSS and the unicode.

Comment: I mean like this one https://image.ibb.co/gBY31U/testset.png